# How to implement long press in Xamarin Forms for iOS?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, long-press

I needed to implement long press in Xamarin Forms for iOS and did not find the post I needed. My working code is below. Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My custom class ImgButton inherits from Grid. In other cases you would just need to replace ViewRenderer with another renderer as per this [table].[1]

As I want long press to be enabled only on certain instances, ImgButton has a property EnableLongPress.

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;
using UIKit;

[assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof(ImgButton), typeof(ImgButtonRenderer))]
namespace MyApp.iOS.Renderers
{
    public class ImgButtonRenderer : ViewRenderer<ImgButton,ImgButtonRenderer>
    {
        private UILongPressGestureRecognizer longPressGestureRecognizer;

    protected override void OnElementChanged ( ElementChangedEventArgs<ImgButton> e )
    {
        base.OnElementChanged ( e );

        if ( e.NewElement != null ) 
        {
            if ( ! e.NewElement.EnableLongPress )
                return;

            Action longPressAction = new Action ( () => 
            {
                if ( longPressGestureRecognizer.State != UIGestureRecognizerState.Began )
                    return;

                Console.WriteLine ( "Long press for " + e.NewElement.Text );

                // Handle the long press in the PCL
                e.NewElement.OnLongPress ( e.NewElement );
            });

            longPressGestureRecognizer = new UILongPressGestureRecognizer ( longPressAction );
            longPressGestureRecognizer.MinimumPressDuration = 0.5D;
            AddGestureRecognizer ( longPressGestureRecognizer );
        }

        if ( e.NewElement == null ) 
        {
            if ( longPressGestureRecognizer != null ) 
            {
                RemoveGestureRecognizer ( longPressGestureRecognizer );
            }
        }

        if ( e.OldElement == null ) 
        {
            if ( longPressGestureRecognizer != null )
                AddGestureRecognizer ( longPressGestureRecognizer );
        }
    }
}
```

And in the ImgButton class:

```
public void OnLongPress ( ImgButton button )
    // Here when a long press happens on an ImgButton
    {
        // Inform current page
        MessagingCenter.Send<ImgButton, ImgButton> ( this, "LongPressMessageType", button );
    }
```

Comment: If the user holds the button down a long time, a system error can result in the messaging subscriber's code being run twice instead of once. In that code you'll need to add something like:

Comment: if ( DateTime.Now - previousLongPressDateTime < new TimeSpan ( 0, 0, 3 ) ) 
                return;